# Augmented Reality - ARToolkit : ar wrapper.dll not found

Tags: artoolkit

I am trying to deploy Augmented Reality done using ARToolkit on another system where unity is not installed.
It works fine in my system

When I deploy in another system. I get below error

ARWrapper.dll not found.

Although I have placed the dll files along with the exe files

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the MS redistributable package from here:
http://www.artoolkit.org/dist/arunity5/5.3/ARUnity5-5.3.2-tools-win.zip

The exe that you need is located in the redist directory inside the package.

Solved the issue for me.
I admit the error message is very misleading.

Comment: I have installed it, but the issue still persists

Comment: Did you provide ARWrapper for the correct CPU type? 32 bit vs 64 bit? What version and CPU type is your development and your target system?

Comment: Hi development is 32 bit and deployment is 64 bit.I have installed 64 bit redist file in 64 bit system.

Comment: Did you also ensure that you copied the 64bit ARWrapper.dll file to the target system?